# SQL adding a new column to check whether ID appears in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, ssms

I work with student data and have two tables with the same structure but different data sets. I would like to add a new column with a record of '0' or '1' to determine whether or not the student appears in the other table. Example:

```
Table 1:
s_id    s_year  s_term  s_crs       NewColumn(was student enrolled in 2016?)
123456  2017    Fall    Math 1010   1
654321  2017    Fall    Eng 1010    0

Table 2:
s_id    s_year  s_term  s_crs 
123456  2016    Fall    Math 2010
432516  2016    Fall    Eng 2010
```

How would you go about doing this?

```
SELECT s_id, s_year, s_term, s_crs 
(CASE 
    WHEN S_ID IN (select s_id from table2)
        THEN '1'
```

or something of that nature? I am unsure how to write this with a join

Answer (score 1):

You could `left join` with the second table, and see if it the resulting column is not null:

```
SELECT    t1.s_id, t1.s_year, t1.s_term, t1.s_crs, 
          CASE WHEN t2.s_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS newcolum
FROM      table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.s_id = t2.s_id
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming table 1 is the result ... using subquery solely based on the s_id and s_year... if there is another requirement please update OP.

```
SELECT
  s_id,
  s_year,
  s_term,
  s_crs,
  ISNULL((SELECT
    1
  FROM table2 t2
  WHERE t2.s_id = t1.s_id
  AND t2.s_year = 2016), 0) [NewCol 2016]
FROM table1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `s_id` is a common identificator

```
SELECT t1.s_id, t1.s_year, t1.s_term, t1.s_crs, 1 as NewColumn
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1.s_id = t2.s_id)
UNION 
SELECT t1.s_id, t1.s_year, t1.s_term, t1.s_crs, 0 as NewColumn
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1.s_id = t2.s_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD NewColumn BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
```

At this point all your items in the *Table1* will be 0, now you just update the needed items with 1

```
UPDATE Table1
SET NewColumn = 1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Left join

```
SELECT    t1.s_id, t1.s_year, t1.s_term, t1.s_crs, 
          CASE WHEN t2.s_Year = '2016' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [NewColumn(was student enrolled in 2016?)]
FROM      table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.s_id = t2.s_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  create table #tbl1
  (
    s_id int,
    s_year varchar(4),
    s_term varchar(4),
    s_crs varchar (10)
  )

  insert into #tbl1 values(123456,'2017','Fall','Math 1010')
  insert into #tbl1 values(654321,'2017','Fall','Eng 1010')

  create table #tbl2
  (
    s_id int,
    s_year varchar(4),
    s_term varchar(4),
    s_crs varchar (10)
  )

  insert into #tbl2 values(123456,'2016','Fall','Math 2010');
  insert into #tbl2 values(432516,'2016','Fall','Eng 2010')


  select a.s_id,a.s_year,a.s_term,a.s_crs,case when b.s_id is null then '0' else '1' end as NewColumn
  from #tbl1 a left outer join #tbl2 b on a.s_id = b.s_id



  drop table #tbl1
  drop table #tbl2
```